# Corona SDK audio tuner on android?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I need to analyse an input data from microphone on real time. For now, I managed to achieve that with media.startTuner() and media.getTunerVolume() and it works great.
However, I also noticed that this function is not supported on Android devices, which I need:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/objectgettunervolume

I tried looking at some openAL "secret" functions with no luck:
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/07/27/the-secretundocumented-audio-apis-in-corona-sdk/

I understand that openAL doesn't let you query the buffer.

Does anyone have any idea about it - is it going to be supported? is there any workaround? am I totally wrong and it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corona SDK does not have a audio tuner on android...

On the forums people are requesting for that, but they gave no timeline yet to implement this, or even if they have the intention to implement this...

So sorry, for now the reply to your question is: cannot do it unless you have Corona Enterprise and use native API.